# Asymptotic series for the inverse Riemann ζ-function

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, inverse-function, conjectures

Consider the positive branch of the Riemann $\zeta$-function: $\zeta:(1,\infty)\to(1,\infty)$ and its inverse $\zeta^{\small(-1)}:(1,\infty)\to(1,\infty)$ satisfying $\zeta\left(\zeta^{\small(-1)}(x)\right) = x$ for $x>1$.

Here are a few initial terms of an asymptotic expansion of $\zeta^{\small(-1)}$ in powers of $x$ (except for the initial term that is logarithmic):
$$\begin{align}\zeta^{\scriptscriptstyle(-1)}(1+x)=-\log_2x+{\small\frac1{\ln2}}\Big(&x^{\log_2\left(\frac32\right)}+x+{\small\log_2\left(\tfrac{\sqrt2}3\right)}\cdot x^{2\log _2\left(\frac32\right)}\\+\,&x^{\log _2\left(\frac52\right)}-{\small\log_2 3}\cdot x^{\log_23}\Big)+\mathcal O\Big(x^{3\log_2\left(\frac32\right)}\Big)\color{gray}{,\,x\to0^+,}\end{align}
$$
or, equivalently,
$$\begin{align}\zeta^{\scriptscriptstyle(-1)}\left(1+2^{-z}\right)=z+{\small\frac1{\ln2}}\Big(&\left(\tfrac32\right)^{-z}+{\small2^{-z}}+{\small\log_2\left(\tfrac{\sqrt2}3\right)}\cdot \left(\tfrac32\right)^{-2z}\\+\,&\left(\tfrac52\right)^{-z}-{\small\log_2 3}\cdot {\small3^{-z}}\Big)+\mathcal O\Big(\left(\tfrac32\right)^{-3z}\Big)\color{gray}{,\,\,z\to\infty.}\end{align}
$$

Can we compute more terms of this series or find a general formula for its terms? Does this series converge?

Comment: An intriguing question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(t)=\zeta(-\log_2 t)-1=t(1+ \sum_{n\ge 3} t^{\log_2 (n) - 1})=t (1+g(t))$$

It is an element of the ring of formal series $$A=\Bbb{R}[[\{t^{1+e}, e\in E\}]], \qquad E= \{ \sum_{l=1}^L m_l (\log_2(n_l)-1), m_l\ge 0, n_l\ge 2\}$$

The main points are that

- the set of exponents $1+E$ is well-ordered, ie. any strictly increasing sequence $\to \infty$,
- for $H(t)=c_0+\sum_{e\in E} c_e t^{1+e}\in A$ then $H(F(t))$ is in $A$:

$$H(F(t))=c_0+\sum_{e\in E} c_e t^{1+e} \sum_{k\ge 0} {1+e\choose k}   g(t)^k \in A$$

**Whence $F(t)$ has an inverse in $A$.**

Start with $G_1=t$, then for $j=1,2,\ldots$

- find $c_j,e_j$ such that $G_j(F(t))= t+c_j t^{1+e_j}(1+o(1))$ and set $G_{j+1}(t) = G_j(t)-c_j t^{1+e_j}$.

We get that $e_j$ is a strictly increasing sequence $\in E$ so $\lim_{j\to \infty} e_j=\infty$ and hence $\lim_{j\to \infty} G_j(t)$ converges in $A$, to $F^{-1}(t)$, giving your asymptotic expansion of $F^{-1}(t)$ at $t=0$ ie. your asymptotic expansion of the inverse of $\zeta(s)$ as $s\to +\infty$.

I don't think the formal series $F^{-1}(t)$ converges for any $t\ne 0$.

Comment: Could you provide a more concrete example showing how to find a few next terms in the series? What is a general form of a coefficient? Is it always a product of a rational number and zero or more binary logarithms of rational numbers, or it becomes more complicated?

Comment: Why are you requesting this? It is a tedious computation of formal series with complicated exponents, but which reduces to the same as what you did, I am just (again, see your previous questions) giving the correct framework to do it.

Comment: I have some difficulties at the step "find $c_j,e_j$ such that $G_j(F(t))= t+c_j t^{1+e_j}(1+o(1))$". How do I exactly find those numbers? I am looking for a general solution that I can implement as an algorithm run by a computer. I calculated a few initial terms using ad hoc methods (and some guesswork) that I do not know how to generalize or put into a precise algorithm.

Comment: Use the $O(t^{2(1+ e_{j-1})})$ approximation of $F$ it will give a $O(t^{2(1+ e_{j-1})})$ approximation of $G_j(F(t))$. If it happens that $e_j\ge 2 (1+e_{j-1})$ then try again with the $O(t^{2^2(1+ e_{j-1})})$ approximation, and so on until you get some non-zero $c_j t^{1+e_j}$ term.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by inverting some formal power series.. (ie. integer exponents) The algorithm is really the same.

Comment: It appears you have solved a slightly different problem. Your series $F^{-1}(t)=t-t^2-t^{\log _23}+{\small\log_23}\cdot t^{\log _2\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)}+\mathcal O\big(t^{\log _25}\big)$ corresponds to $2^{-\zeta^{\small(-1)}(t+1)}$, while mine (stripped of log terms and multiplied by a factor to take a similar shape) $t-t^2-t^{\log _23}+{\small\log_2\left(\tfrac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\cdot t^{\log _2\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)}+\mathcal O\big(t^{\log _25}\big)$ corresponds to $t\cdot\big(1-\ln t-\ln2\cdot\zeta^{\small(-1)}(t+1)\big).$

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement your suggested approach as an algorithm. It confirmed a few terms included in my question (that I computed manually) and a few terms beyond them. It is not fast, but it is moving forward. Perhaps, I will be able to optimize it further.

Comment: It appears that all powers are binary logarithms of dyadic rationals: $\frac{3}{2},{\small2},\frac{9}{4},\frac{5}{2},{\small3},\frac{27}{8},\frac{7}{2},\frac{15}{4},{\small4},\frac{9}{2},{\small5},\frac{81}{16}.$

Comment: The exponents are of the form $1+\sum_{l=1}^L m_l (\log_2(n_l)-1)$ :-) When your denominator is $2^k$ the numerator must have at least $k+1$ prime factors with multiplicity

Comment: When multiplied by 16, these rationals agree with an initial segment of this sequence: https://oeis.org/A033987 "Numbers that are divisible by at least 4 primes (counted with multiplicity)"